# Sacar nuevo campo cruzando con otra tabla consulta grande

Tags: sql, oracle

Estaba intentando modificar una consulta existente usando oracle sql developer 18.0.3 tengo una consulta grande

Adjunto la consulta para que quede más claro

```
<entry key="descriptor.pers">
        WITH t1 as (select t1ID,
            listagg(nvl(cod,'#'), ',')
            within group (order by cod) as codes,
            listagg(nvl(name,'#'), ',')
            within group (order by name) as names,
            listagg(nvl(ar,'#'), ',')
            within group (order by ar) as ars
            from de
        group by t1ID)   
        select 
            t2.t1ID as t1ID, 
            t2.nom, 
            t2.tr as tr, t2.bl as bl, t2.dn as dn, t2.ta as ta,  
            t2.fi, t2.ff,
            t2.INO,
            ex.codes as cicod,
            ex.names as ciname,
            ex.ars as ciorg, 
            null as ticom,
            null as dticom,
            t3.nl as nl,
            t3.cft,
            t2.dcc AS dcc,
            t2.aai ,
        from greet t2
        join free t3 on t2.t1ID = t3.t1ID and t3.nl = :calda
        left join t1 ex on ex.t1ID= t2.t1ID
    where 1 = 1 
        #if($params.cName) and t2.nom = :cName #end         
        #if($params.cSurname) and t2.tr = :cSurname #end
        #if($params.cColour) and t2.bl = :cColour #end
        #if($params.cExt) and t2.ta = :cExt #end
        #if($params.cOrd) and t2.dn = :cOrd #end
        #if($params.cBegin) and t2.fi = :cBegin #end
        #if($params.cEnd) and t2.ff = :cEnd #end
        #if($params.calda) and t3.nl = :calda #end
        #if($params.area) 
            and trim(t2.aai)=:area
        #end
        #if( $params.isOld == 'N' )
            AND  (trunc(t2.ff)  <![CDATA[>=]]> trunc(sysdate) or t2.ff is null)
        #end


        order by t2.dn, t2.t1ID desc    
    </entry>
```

Quería hacer un filtrado de los resultados ya obtenidos por esta consulta, para sacar solo los que no aparezcan en una nueva tabla t4 cuyo t4.scid se corresponde con la tabla greet t2.scid

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Que quiere decir que es una consulta grande? y sin ver los datos que estas cruzando, y como se cruzan las tablas, va a ser muy dificil ayudarte. un explain plan tambien puede ayudar con tu problema